# Website elements go haywire when the user zooms in or out. How do I keep them from moving?

Tags: html, css

So I have been designing a website and designed the front page with no problems using padding to center everything nicely. I finally got everything the way I wanted it to be centered and all. I then realized when I zoomed my page out things went in 2 directions. My "Photo Gallery" went right and the main table with info in it went left. Now I know this is because the elements are designated to float or align right/left. However, I need to know how to make them stay proportionate at different zooms if you will. Thanks in advance! Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<HTML>
<Center>
<Body>

 </Center>
 <div class="gallery" align="right">
 <img src="photo-gallery.jpg" width="225" Height="200"> <Br>
 <center>
 <a href="Photo-Gallery.php" class="myButton">Photo Gallery</a>
 </center>
 </div>

 <Div class="front" align="left">
 <table border="5">
 <tr>
 <th>
 (TEXT)
 </th>
 </table>

 <table border="5">
 <td> 
 <p>
 (TEXT)
 </P>
 <Td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>
</Body>
```

CSS:

```
table {
width: 600px;
font-size: 35px;
background-color: #e5e2d9 ;
border-color: #444;

}

.gallery {
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 475px;
width: 225;
height: 200;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
position: relative; 


} 

.front {
padding-left: 439px


}

p {
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to tackle this is to use [% width/padding](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/width/) instead of `px`width.

Just change your CSS:

```
table {
width: 60%;/*Check note below*/
font-size: 35px;
background-color: #e5e2d9 ;
border-color: #444;    
}

.gallery {
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 20%; /*Check note below*/
width: 225;
height: 200;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
position: relative;  
} 

.front {
padding-left: 20% /*Check note below*/
}

p {
font-size: 20px;
}
```

***NOTE : You may want to play around with the numbers to get a perfect webpage , I have just provided some random numbers to help you understand the concept of % width ***

Comment: Could you explain briefly how to put this into practice and how it would fix the situation?

Comment: Ok I can see how this might work, however, is there anyway to keep them from expanding with the page and keep them at a certain percent? So for instance this makes the table get wider and wider as you expand. I see how this can work, however, most webpages have things stay the same size as you zoom out. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @Xxcoder14xX then use position:fixed instead of position:relative

Comment: This does not appear to work. The table is just moved up onto the other elements for some reason. Is i possible another position type might be more suited for this?